# Time formula for a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

This is the formula I have:

```
(DATEDIFF('CUSTTRANS-SGCUSTDEBTSETTLEMENT'[TRANSDATE];TODAY();DAY))
```

Now I would like to have a formula where I can show the time difference in a period of time, like 1 year old or 1,5 years old.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results that covers all possible cases please.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to reuse it. this covers all possible units

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertTimeToPeriodFormat        
(     
  @FROM_DATE DATETIME,     
  @TO_DATE DATETIME        
)   
RETURNS  
VARCHAR(100)    
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @Date  
AS  
VARCHAR(100)      
SELECT  @Date = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 1   
THEN'1 min old'  
WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) > 1  AND DATEDIFF(mi, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 60  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mi, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' mins old'WHEN DATEDIFF(hh, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 1  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' hour old'WHEN DATEDIFF(hh, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) > 1  AND DATEDIFF(hh, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 24  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' hrs old'WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 1  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' day old'WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) > 1  AND DATEDIFF(dd, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 7  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' days old'WHEN DATEDIFF(ww, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 1  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(ww, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' week old'WHEN DATEDIFF(ww, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) > 1  AND DATEDIFF(ww, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 4  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(ww, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' weeks old'WHEN DATEDIFF(mm, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 1  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mm, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' month old'WHEN DATEDIFF(mm, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) > 1  AND DATEDIFF(mm, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 12  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mm, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' months old'WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) <= 1  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(yy, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' year old'WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE) > 1  THEN  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(yy, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE))  + ' years old'END  
RETURN @Date  
END
```

and you can use it as

```
select dbo.ConvertTimeToPeriodFormat('YourDateHere',GETDATE()) [Date]
```

Comment: @DebbieWitsenburg don't forget to mark it as answer, that will help many others as well :)